# Set Keyframes for Drivers

Tags: animation, keyframes, drivers

I'm trying to animate some Gears with Drivers. With the Expression '(bpy.context.scene.frame_current)/10' it works very well. The gears are rotating from begin to end of the frame range, but I would something like begin to rotate after a few seconds (like at frame 300), when another object activates a switch for the gears.
Can I set a Keyframe for the Driver, where the Driver has to be activated?
It's the first time I work with Drivers so I have no ideas for the correct solution.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: The current frame is known to drivers as `frame`  For the delay start could use `max(frame - 300, 0) / 10`